# scrapy + splash response incomplete page

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen

I have scraped this url, https://www.disco.com.ar/prod/409496/at%C3%BAn-en-aceite-jumbo-120-gr for months in order to get the price for example. But last week I couldn't. I don't understand what change. Because the response only return the icon but not the HTML.

I use scrapy + splash.

[Here the example of the response in splash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NsYo.png)

I changed the setting in the scrapy, also the LUA in splash but nothing working.

Comment: That URL takes _a lot_ to load here. Maybe you need to increase the wait time of Splash? How long is your wait time at the moment?

Comment: Hi Gallaecio, I tried with different number, actually it is in 300 (--max-timeout 300)